# Can't connect to memcached server on localhost, how to debug?

Tags: memcached, telnet

I'm running memcached, but can't connect. How should I start to debug this? Something appears to be stopping me connecting.

ps -elf | grep memcached
0 S lee      10744   529  0  80   0 - 30529 ep_pol 03:36 pts/22   00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 512 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1

(Memcached is definitely running)

But when I try to telnet in, I get a timeout.

telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your firewall is running?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the local loopback network interface is running. It sounds like you're using a Unix system, so I would recommend running `/sbin/ifconfig` to see if a section labeled lo with the IP address (labeled as the inet addr) `127.0.0.1` is up and running. If not, run ifdown lo then ifup lo, this should get it going. Read your `/etc/hosts` file to make sure that localhost or you machine's name is bound to `127.0.0.1`. And if your machine is using ipchains or iptables, ensure that those are configured to let traffic pass to `127.0.0.1` from `127.0.0.1`.

These things are all fine 99% of the time, but being unable to connect to localhost is indeed odd, so a sanity check is in order.

Comment: As another sanity check, ensure the memcached configuration has not changed. It looks like 11211 is the default port, but perhaps someone changed that on you. This sort of misconfiguration typically causes a Connect failed message in place of a Connect timed out message, however.

Comment: As a second sanity check, make sure your etc/hosts has an entry for localhost ("127.0.0.1 localhost"). My engineering team is still rolling on the ground laughing after I accidentally emptied my hosts configuration while pasting documentation in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any firewall enabled. In my case I found following entries for `iptables`:

```
target     prot opt source                destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  example.com.internal  anywhere             tcp dpt:11211
ACCEPT     udp  --  example.com.internal  anywhere             udp dpt:11211
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere              anywhere             tcp dpt:11211
DROP       udp  --  anywhere              anywhere             udp dpt:11211
```

They allow connection only from the `example.com.internal` and deny from anywhere else, including `localhost`. To fix that I added specific rule for `localhost`:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost             anywhere             tcp dpt:11211
ACCEPT     udp  --  localhost             anywhere             udp dpt:11211
```